# CAST inside WHERE, how can I do it?

Tags: sql

Is it possible to do:

```
WHERE (SELECT CAST(dateFrom as date) FROM Bookings) = @day
```

If yes how to do it properly?

Comment: You should explain what you want done.  It is not immediately obvious.

Comment: Please see [ask]. The idea is you tell us what you want to do, show what you tried and the research you did, and say what went wrong via an [edit].

Comment: What DBMS are you using? SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL? ... And yes, please tell us what you want to achieve. So far your where clause is "only select data when the list of days in the booking table matches the value in the variable @day", which makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like you are trying to do this:

```
select * from Bookings
WHERE CAST(dateFrom as date)  = @day
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only do that if `bookings` has zero or 1 row.

You can do:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Bookings b WHERE CAST(b.dateFrom as date) = @day)
```

This will check if `Bookings.datefrom` matches `@day`, which seems like a reasonable guess as to what you want to do.

Comment: It says `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE' `